# Is there a way to widen the possible width range for Apple Pencil drawings in PencilKit?

Tags: ios, swift, pencilkit, apple-pencil

Most high-end drawing apps on the iPad provide a means to edit the "pressure curve" of the Apple Pencil, namely how much adding pressure affects the width of the line created. Apple's **PencilKit** provides tools (e.g., a "pen") with pressure-sensitive widths, but the width varies within a relatively tight range.

Several structs (e.g., [`InkType`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/pencilkit/pkinkingtool/inktype)) provide a means to set a "valid width range," and the [`PKInkingTool`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/pencilkit/pkinkingtool) allows the width of the ink to be specified, but I can't seem to find a way to adjust the range of valid widths for a single stroke.

As far as I can tell, this is the limit of configurability of a tool's behavior

```
let tool = PKInkingTool(.pen, color: .black, width: CGFloat(10))
```

Is there a way to create a custom tool or otherwise specify additional configuration? Ideally, I'd like to create a pen tool equivalent that allowed for smoother variation between large and small lines. The current tool seems rather limited in its utilization of the pressure sensitivity of the pencil.

Comment: Did you solve it? I'm trying to do something similar, creating a constant width tool..

Comment: Alas, not yet. There might be some more options from recent iOS updates, but I doubt it.